# Any example of uploading files using activeweb?

Tags: javalite, activeweb

I try to upload some csv files to server side and process them and save to database, any example about uploading file in activeweb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kitchensink example has an upload demo: https://github.com/javalite/kitchensink.

Here is the sample of code that can process multipart POST request:

```
public class UploadController extends AppController {

    public void index() {}

    @POST
    public void save() throws IOException {
        List<FormItem> items = multipartFormItems();
        List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (FormItem item : items) {
            if(item.isFile()){
                messages.add("Found file: " + item.getFileName() + " with size: " + Util.read(item.getInputStream()).length());
            }else{
                messages.add("Found field: " + item.getFieldName() + " with value: " + item.getStreamAsString());
            }
        }
        flash("messages", messages);
        redirect(UploadController.class);
    }
}
```

On the Freemarker side:

```
<@form controller="upload" action="save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select a file to upload:<input type="file" name="file">

<input name="book" value="The Great Gatsby" type="text">
    <button>Upload File</button>
</@>
```

I hope this code is easy to follow.

Comment: Thanks, @ipolevoy. It helps a lot!

Comment: My reputation is too low to upvote... I will upvote it when it reaches 15 points